# Вопрос по оптимизации

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Вообщем интересует следующее. Например у меня есть вывод информации о пользователе:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 1
```

Например я хочу вывести его фотографии из таблицы, я создаю новый запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `photo` WHERE `from_id` = 1
```

Ещё допустим хочу вывести аудиозаписи

```
SELECT * FROM `audio` WHERE `from_id` = 1
```

На всё это уходит 3 запроса. Правильно ли я делаю? Или нужно как-то иначе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно всё это объединить в 1 запрос, он будет более тяжелый чем 3 написанных выше, и он будет занимать всё больше времени с ростом строк в таблицах users, photo, audio.

Можете смело использовать 3 запроса.

З.Ы. Единственный вариант для такой ситуации оптимазации это не забыть проставить индексы :)))

Comment: @Зоркий, как я понял, индексы нужны на from_id. Так?

Comment: @ModaL, да.